# Accordion does not size correctly when set to collapsible and heightstyle fill

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLygQ/

```
<div class="accordion" style="max-height:600px">
<h3>Cats</h3>
     <div>
          Some content
          <br/>
          Some more content
     </div>
 </div>
<span>No whitespace above me</span>
```

.

```
$(function() {
    $(".accordion").accordion({ heightStyle: "fill", collapsible: true, active: false });
});
```

Basically, if you set it to fill it will not adjust the height correctly if collapsible is set to true.

If you disable collapsible, or you set the heightstyle to content, it will work correctly. However I require a collapsible accordion that sizes based on its content.

I have set the max height to 600px which is far in excess of the content size, as I want accordions that have too much content to have a scrollbar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the max-height on the accordion content and set the heightStyle to fill then you get the functionality that you want. No scroll for single line, scrollbar for anything over max. See: http://jsfiddle.net/4RN7v/1/

```
    $(function() {
    $(".accordion").accordion({ heightStyle: "content", collapsible: true, active: true });
    $(".ui-accordion-content").css("max-height", "200px");
});
```

*phew*. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't quite work, if you type some text below eg http://jsfiddle.net/3PHUy/ you can see it has reserved the space beneath it. I also need to set a min-height because I don't know what the height should be, only the max-height. However setting max-height does not work.

Comment: @SLC Sorry to be dense but why do you need a min and max height and not merely a height if you want the content to overflow-scroll? Surely it would make the rest of your page design simpler?

Comment: I want the accordion to take up no space, so you just see the button to expand it and content beneath. Then when you click it, it expands to show the content. If the content is one line, it only expands to show one line. If the content is very long, then it expands to a maximum of 300px and shows a scrollbar.

Comment: See update, I think this is what you're after. Obviously will become a bit more tricky if you have multiple accordions with differing max-heights.